# Android cannot find class java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection? Trying to put string on clipboard

Tags: java, android, class, clipboard

I am trying to copy a stack trace to my clipboard in android so that when the app crashes people can report the bug to me if they want to. I am using this method:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(exceptionAsString);
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(selection, null);
```

It works wonderfully when I run the program on my desktop (I am using LibGDX to deploy the game on desktop and android) but when I try to run it in android I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection` error.

Does android not support the StringSelection class? Are their alternative ways to doing this that work on both android and desktop? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Updated the answer for a multiplatform solution. 
Here's an idea, what I would try to do:

1. detect platform, I'm not sure what will work here, you'll need to try, maybe `Build.VERSION.SDK`
2. as you mentioned, the awt class does not load on the Android device, so when we're running on android, we'll not try to load it at all.
3. when we'll running on desktop, we'll try to load awt classes dynamically.

For the android part, you do not need StringSelection class.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();

if (isAndroidPlatform()){
  ClipboardManager myClipboard;
  myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
  ClipData myClip;
  myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", exceptionAsString);
  myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
} else {
    ClassLoader classLoader = YourMainClass.class.getClassLoader();
    Class stringSelectionClass = classLoader.loadClass("java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection");
    Constructor constructor = stringSelectionClass.getConstructor(String.class);
    Object stringSelection =  constructor.newInstance(exceptionAsString);

    //you can try to access dynamically the awt clipboard along these lines, using java.lang.reflection
    Class toolkitSelectionClass = classLoader.loadClass("java.awt.Toolkit");
    Method toolkitConstructor = toolkitSelectionClass.getMethod("getDefaultToolkit");
    Object toolkit = toolkitConstructor.invoke(null);
    Method clipboardConstructor = toolkitSelectionClass.getMethod("getSystemClipboard");
    Object clipBoard = clipboardConstructor.invoke(toolkit);
    Class transferableClass = classLoader.loadClass("java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable");
    Class clipboardOwnerClass = classLoader.loadClass("java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner");
    Method copyMethod = clipBoard.getClass().getMethod("setContents", transferableClass, clipboardOwnerClass);
    copyMethod.invoke(clipBoard, stringSelection, null);

}
```

Android Docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Comment: Like I said in my question, I want this to work in both android and on desktop computers. A lot of this code is android only. The only options I have are Java methods or LibGDX methods.

Comment: @vedi0boy, forgive my laziness, I missed that part, that you want to be able to run this both on desktop and Android device. I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will upvote you for your effort but it is not a good solution for my problem. I cannot use ANY android sdk classes. LibGDX is used to port from desktop to android and vice-versa only using java code and code included in the LibGDX api. Your answer may help someone else though, but not me. Sorry.

Comment: Ohh, I got you now, I added an other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is you are try to use [java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html) here:

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
```

I suggest you try to use LibGDX [com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Clipboard](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Clipboard.html)

See example here: http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11503&p=51773

Comment: This does not actually affect the OS's clipboard. I tried it. It's just sample code to make an in-program clipboard. All it does is has a content String variable with getters and setters to manipulate and read it. Sorry none of your answers work, it's alright, I can still do it the other way on Desktop and on android, google provides a crash reporter in the google developer console.